# Strict condition check on each element of jsonb array postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a table **master_data_approval_table** in my postgres DB having field **approval_value** (type Jsonb) which contains below structure:

[image]

We want only those records where each object of jsonb array strictly matches the given condition **"status": "Approved"**

Expected O/P:

[image]

I tried with different queries but didn't find the exact query to get the expected output. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT approval_value
FROM master_data_approval_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(approval_value) arr
   WHERE arr->>'status' <> 'Approved'
);
```

The jsonb_array_elements function will expand the jsonb array into separate rows, and then you can filter those rows based on the condition.

This query will return the rows from the master_data_approval_table where all objects in the jsonb array have "status": "Approved".

Answer (score 2):

First flatten the JSONB field and then do a routine select.

```
select mdat.* from master_data_approval_table mdat
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(approval_value) as l
group by id 
having count(*) filter (where l ->> 'status' = 'Approved') = count(*);
```

I assume that master_data_approval_table.id is the primary key. If not then replace `select mdat.*` with `select mdat.id` in the query above.
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48aR9arV27S4rUscKVDnEZ/0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want:

`SELECT * FROM master_data_approval_table
WHERE (approval_value::jsonb)->>'status' = 'Approved'`

For some reason if you try to select `json_field->>'json_object'` you get an error, so you need to (somewhat redundantly) cast your json field to json.

Comment: Can you tell me what (if any) error are you getting? Because I query a lot of jsonb fields and this is definitely the correct syntax.

Comment: not getting any error with empty result

Comment: My bad - didn't see it was a jsonb array. @Stefanov.sm's solution should work.